# What is an "s" inside "$-"?

Tags: bash, shell-builtin

I'm normally well aware of the contents of `$-`.  On a recent CentOS I get:

```
[grochmal@orion ~]$ echo $-
himBH
```

`hmBH` are all options from `set`, and `i` means that my shell is interactive.

Yet, on my Arch Linux I got:

```
[grochmal@haps ~]$ echo $-
himBHs
```

I cannot find anything useful in `man bash` and `set -s` gives me an error.  What does that `s` stand for?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `-s` option is the bash start call with `-s`, which means "source commands from "standard in". From the manual:

> -s
>   If the -s option is present, or if no arguments remain after option processing, then commands are read from the standard input.  This option allows the positional parameters to  be  set  when  invoking  an interactive shell.

It is very easy to test:

```
$ bash -c 'echo $-'
hBc

$ bash -sc 'echo $-'
hBcs
```

Starting a new shell for all previous bash versions doesn't set that option by default:

```
$ b32sh -li
$ echo $-
himBH
```

But it is in bash 4.4:

```
$ b44sh -li
$ echo $-
himBHs
```

Comment: And the second part explains why I got that on Arch.  My CentOS' value for `BASH_VERSION` is 4.2.46(1)-release whilst on Arch is it 4.4.5(1)-release.